# jetpack compose not responding to keyboard input on emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

```
 var email = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
                OutlinedTextField(
                    value = email.value,
                    onValueChange = {
                        checkUserName(it.text, hint1)
                        email.value = it
                    },
                    label = { Text(getString(R.string.signIn_email_hint)) },

                )
```

The software keyboard works while keyboard has no response.

Other project not using jetpack compose runs on the same emulator and keyboard works just fine with EditText.

Can anyone help?

I'm sure relative config in emulator are checked

AS version: Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 4

jetpack compose version = "1.0.0-alpha10"

**This Problem has been solved in Compose version 1.0.0-beta04 with AS version: Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Beta 1**

Answer (score 1):

There is a ticket opened for this issue.
Looks like the fix was merged already, so it should be available soon.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170188271

Answer (score 0):

Just ditch the `TextFieldValue()` and use the mutable state of a regular string. It works just fine. Even on the emulator with hard input as far as I would think.